# Residuals plot with strange pattern

Tags: random-forest, residuals

I fit a random forest classifier to my data after applying StratifiedShuffleSplit

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
sss.get_n_splits(X, y)
StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, random_state=0)
for train_index, test_index in sss.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

I have a multiclass task with classes= [11,  0,  5,  7, 16,  2, 10,  9, 15, 14, 13,  1,  4,  8, 12,  6,  3]

and my dataset is unbalanced:

```
|Class| Count
|3    |  49
|6    |  65
|12   |  152
|4    |  245
|14   |  409
|1    |  447
|13   |  574
|7    | 1040
|16   | 1287
|2    | 1596
|5    | 1842
|0    | 1953
|10   | 2200
|8    | 2482
|15   | 2505
|11   | 6030
|9    | 7187
```

Then I plotted a residuals plot to see if everything was alright but I get a pattern on the plot that I don't know how to interpret.

[image: Residuals plot from random forest classifier]

EDITED:

The code that I used for the plot is:

`matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6.0, 6.0)  preds_TEST = pd.DataFrame({"preds":model.predict(X_test), "true":y_test}) preds_TEST["residuals"] = preds_TEST["true"] - preds_TEST["preds"] preds_TEST.plot(x = "preds", y = "residuals",kind = "scatter")`

**What does the pattern in the plot mean?**

Comment: You say you are running a classifier but the plot seems to suggest that you predict quantitative numbers (I don't know the function that you use there but if I'm not mistaken, you don't show the function that produced the plot, so I suspect it will be hard for anyone to give an informed answer).

Comment: @Lewian The code that I used to do the plot is this one:
`matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (6.0, 6.0)

preds_TEST = pd.DataFrame({"preds":model.predict(X_test), "true":y_test})
preds_TEST["residuals"] = preds_TEST["true"] - preds_TEST["preds"]
preds_TEST.plot(x = "preds", y = "residuals",kind = "scatter")`

Comment: @Lewian I have categories that were encoded to numbers: 11,  0,  5,  7, 16,  2, 10,  9, 15, 14, 13,  1,  4,  8, 12,  6,  3.

Comment: But the plot seems to treat them as having quantitative meaning. I don't know the software so if you want me to have any chance to comment, you need to explain in words and mathematical terms where these residuals come from. I suspect you may have applied a random forest regression to a classification problem, which is wrong, but I can't know that not being familiar with the software you're apparently using.